# Derive MA (Moving average) representation of a first-difference-process

Tags: time-series, arima, stochastic-processes, stationarity, autoregressive

I have a non-stationary AR(1)-process. After taking the first difference, how can I derive the MA representation of the resulting „difference process“ Delta_xt?

As an example, consider

x<sub>t</sub> = 1.5x<sub>t-1</sub> + e<sub>t</sub>

<=>
(x<sub>t</sub>-x<sub>t-1</sub>=) Delta_x<sub>t</sub> = 0.5x<sub>t-1</sub> + e<sub>t</sub>.

How can I convert this process Delta_xt into an MA process?

Comment: You don't do differencing.  You do back substitution, So substitute 1.5 X(t-2) + e(t-1) for X(t-1) making X(t) = (1.5)$^2$ X(t-2) + 1.5 e(t-1) + e(t)  and continue t substitute for X(t-2) and so forth in the same way to get the infinite moving average representation. The infinite series of the e(t) is divergent which shows that the process is non stationary

Comment: But I am looking for the MA representation of the „difference-process“ Delta_xt. I don’t want the MA of the original process.

Comment: That isn't what your title said and it wasn't explained in the question.

Comment: I changed the text and hope that my question is clearer now. I would still appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem has a simple solution, which is that the AR(1) process you are describing is not stationary. Thus, it does not admit a moving average representation.

However, the more general problem can be relevant.

For some intuition, consider a stationary AR(1) model with an autoregressive parameter $\beta$, and assume it has been transformed into an MA($\infty$) model with moving average parameters $1,\beta,\beta^{2},...$. When considering the difference of that process, the coefficients are such that you need to difference the original MA($\infty$) model. So if the aforementioned coefficients were $1,\beta,\beta^{2},...$, then the differenced MA coefficients are $1,\beta-1,\beta^{2}-\beta,...$.

It's perhaps easiest to convert this into a state space form. We can combine together both the difference equation and the level equation into one form
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\Delta y_{t}\\
y_{t}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \beta-1\\
0 & \beta
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
\Delta y_{t-1}\\
y_{t-1}
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}\right]\varepsilon_{t}
$$
Simplifying some of the notation, we can write this as
$$
X_{t}=AX_{t-1}+B\varepsilon_{t}
$$
Which through some standard time series techniques implies
$$
X_{t}=\left(1-AL\right)^{-1}B\varepsilon_{t}
$$
We can extract the difference series as
$$
\Delta y_{t}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\end{array}\right]\left(1-AL\right)^{-1}B\varepsilon_{t}
$$
Note that $$\left(1-AL\right)^{-1}$$ is fairly standard in time series and expands to $$I+AL+\left(AL\right)^{2}+..$$

This can easily be extended to an AR(p) process and adding in constants, etc.

Comment: Hi John: it's an interesting idea but those two state space equations conflict. You can't difference the first one ( without differencing the error term also )  so the first equation in the state space representation can't have the same error term as the second one. As you said, the original equation is not-stationary so I don't think it's possible to do what the OP asked.